# Deleting keys with subkeys

Tags: c++, windows, registry

How I can delete in Windows c++ registry keys with subkeys? RegDeleteKey() doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SHDeleteKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773486(VS.85).aspx) can be used to delete a key and all of its sub keys.

Comment: On Vista and above, use RegDeleteTree()

Answer (score 0):

CSharp has a DeleteSubKeyTree.